# The list of table elements found by Xpath contains only visible ten elements with correct text values that could be received throug getText() method

Tags: java, list, selenium, webdriver

1. I want to get a List of WebElement objects from framable table and go through it getting texts using getText() method in case if number of elements is greater than 10. Only 10 columns are visible for user.
2. My table is framed and shows only 10 columns at time, so findElements gets only these ten column names.

Code, that I used to get my column values:
Code:

```
public void getColumnsList() throws Exception{
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//*[contains(@id, 'window-')]//*[contains(@id, '-textContainerEl')]));
    for (WebElement el:elements){
        System.out.println(elements.indexOf(el)+" element "+el.getText());
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
0 element Column1 
1 element Column2 
2 element Column3 
3 element Column4 
4 element Column5 
5 element Column6 
6 element Column7 
7 element Column8 
8 element Column9 
9 element Column10 
10 element Column11 
11 element Column12 
12 element Column13 
13 element Column14
14 element Column15
```

Actual result:

```
0 element Column1 
1 element Column2 
2 element Column3 
3 element Column4 
4 element Column5 
5 element Column6 
6 element Column7 
7 element Column8 
8 element Column9 
9 element Column10 
10 element 
11 element 
12 element 
13 element 
14 element
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's not clear to me why you expect `Column11` through `Column15` in your output.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (with focus on "Verifiable") that demonstrates your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of driver.findElements always sees only visible part of my framable table it was required to get text values into separate lists directly, moving through all cells of the entire row (I was needed the first row cells also):

```
public TableElements getTableElements() throws Exception {
    if (getColumnsList()!=null) {

        List<WebElement> elements = getColumnsList();
        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ListIterator<WebElement> listItr = null;
        int columnsNumber = elements.size();
        System.out.println("columnsNumber is: " + columnsNumber + " in " + driver.findElement(By.xpath(datasource)).getText());
        WebElement cell = driver.findElement(By.xpath(getValue("firstColumnXpath")));
        cell.click();
        listItr = elements.listIterator();
        while (listItr.hasNext()) {
            columnNames.add(listItr.next().getText());
            rowValues.add(driver.switchTo().activeElement().getText());
        driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);
        }
        return new TableElements(columnNames, rowValues);
    }
    else {
        return new TableElements(null, null);
    }
}

public List<WebElement> getColumnsList() throws Exception {
    if (CSSElementExists(getValue("columnLabelsCSS")))
        return driver.findElements(By.xpath(getValue("columnLabelsXpath")));
    return null;
}
```